# Cakephp 3 Search plugin get related fields

Tags: cakephp, search, cakephp-3.0

I'm using the [Easy model searching](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/search) plugin from FriendsOfCake and use it to search into my table data. It's working very good but now I wan't to get related items by a foreign key that matched with the foreign key of the founded item.

On this moment my query is returning only the row by the content I search for, but how can I define that I also want the other rows with the same forKey?

My table looks like:

```
ID     | forKey | name    | content 
------ | ------ | ------  | ------
1      | 1      | value1  | content1  
2      | 1      | value2  | content2
3      | 2      | value3  | content3
```

Search function inside Controller:

```
 $query = $this->Content
         ->find('search', [
             'search' => $this->request->getQuery()
         ]);
```

Search setup inside Controller Table:

```
public function initialize(array $config) {
    parent::initialize($config);

    // Search
    $this->addBehavior('Search.Search');

    // Setup search filter using search manager

    $this->searchManager()
//            ->value('id')
        ->add('q', 'Search.Like', [
            'before' => true,
            'after' => true,
            'fieldMode' => 'OR',
            'comparison' => 'LIKE',
            'wildcardAny' => '*',
            'wildcardOne' => '?',
            'field' => ['content'],
        ])
        ->add('foo', 'Search.Callback', [
            'callback' => function ($query, $args, $filter) {
                // Modify $query as required
            }]);
}
```

Comment: I haven't yet used this plugin, but it seems that putting `$query->contain([...])` in the callback might work? Or add a `->contain` clause after the `find('search')`?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you're trying to find things that match your criteria in more than one field or if you're trying to find it in a related table.

For searching more fields from the calling table just add them comma separated:

```
'field' => ['content', 'id', 'name'],
```

If you are looking to bind the search to related items in other tables then include those in the controller search as contain:

```
$query = $this->Content
     ->find('search', [
         'search' => $this->request->getQuery()
     ])
      ->contain(['OtherRelatedTable']);
```

Then add those to the model call:

```
'field' => ['content', 'id', 'name', 'OtherRelatedTable.id'],
```

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to filter using an associated model, use either the callback option or a custom finder:

```
$searchManager->add('related_table_field', 'Search.Callback', [
    'callback' => function ($query, $args, $filter) {
        $related_table_field = $args['related_table_field'];
        $query->matching('RelatedTable', function ($q) use($related_table_field) {
            return $q->where(['RelatedTable.related_table_field LIKE' => '%'.$related_table_field.'%']);
        });
      }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->add('q', 'Search.Like', [
                'before' => true,
                'after' => true,
                'fieldMode' => 'OR',
                'comparison' => 'LIKE',
                'wildcardAny' => '*',
                'wildcardOne' => '?',
                'field' => ['firstname', 'username']
            ])
            ->add('table_name.address', 'Search.Callback', [
                'callback' => function ($query, $args, $filter) {
                    $query->matching('TableModel', function ($q) use($args) {
                                return $q->where(['TableModel.address' => $args['table_name.address']]);
                            });
                    return $query;
                }
    ]);
```